# Regex help for custom fields in emails

Tags: php, regex, ckeditor

I allow custom fields in emails sent out in my software. I use CKEditor so they can write and format their emails. And example of a HTML formatted email with a custom field is:

> <p>Hi %firstname%,</p>
>
> <p>Blah blah blah.....</p>

I use the following code to detect and replace those fields.

```
preg_match_all('`\%(?![0-9])([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)\%`', $message, $contact_fields);
if (!empty($contact_fields[1])) {
    foreach($contact_fields[1] AS $contact_field) {
        $replace_width = 'do the magic here';
        $message = str_replace('%' . $contact_field . '%', $replace_with, $message);
    }
}
```

The issue is sometimes CKEditor does this:

> <p>Hi %<span>firstname</span>%,</p>
>
> <p>Blah blah blah.....</p>

So it doesn't end up replacing the fields. And my users are wondering why this is because they cannot see the HTML code.

Any suggestion on how I can make this regex work so thatif  or any other HTML attribute ends up inside my custom fields, it will still replace it?

Thanks

Ben

Comment: Is the problem with the `preg_match` or the `str_replace`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go:

```
\%(?![0-9])(?:<[^<]+?>)?([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)(?:[\s]?<[^<]+?>)?\%
```

I added `(?:<[^<]+?>)?` before and after your capturing group.
`(?:...)` groups characters without creating a capture group, `<[^<]+?>` matches html-tags and the last `?` makes this optional. So this will match when html-tags are present and also when they're not.
In the second non-capturing group i inserted `[\s]?` before matching an html-tag, as in your example there is a single space between `firstname` and `</span>`.

Example can be found here: http://regexr.com?372fe

If you want to include the html-tags in the capturing groups, just shift the brackets to create a large capturing group matching `<tag>string</tag>`:

```
\%(?![0-9])((?:<[^<]+?>)?[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+(?:[\s]?<[^<]+?>)?)\%
```

Comment: Awesome! The only issue is I need it to return any HTML it finds so that my `str_replace` works. At the moment it returns just `firstname` instead of `<span>firstname</span>`. Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: @BenSinclair Sure. You just have to shift the brackets to create a new capturing group. Remove the brackets around `[a-zA-z0-9_-]+` and instead enclose the non-capturing groups including your main string in brackets. See my edit.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. I tried that already but when I ran the test it only picks up `%<span>firstname</span>%` and not `%firstname%` anymore.

Comment: @BenSinclair I put the last bracket in the wrong place, it has to be behind `?`, edited it!

Comment: Working perfectly. Really appreciate your time helping with this ;)

Answer (score 2):

I think the mistake is "A-z" instead of "A-Z". Try this:

```
preg_match_all('`\%(?![0-9])([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)\%`', $message, $contact_fields);
```

Comment: Thanks I've fixed this. But this doesn't have any affect on what I'm trying to achieve :)

Comment: This was not the main problem, I was going to edit about the <span> but @Basti_M probably gave the best answer

Comment: yeah, I notice that after I answered. I was going to suggest to make your regex less restrictive, something like `#%([^ %]*)%#` (anything but space or the `%` delimiter) then a strip_tag(). But that can cause other problems.

Comment: For the completeness i corrected the `A-z` mistake in my answer. Actually i wasn't paying attention towards this - thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, how do you then add logic to determine which unwanted text within the `%...%` is HTML markup which is safe to be removed vs. part of the custom field name.  My suggestion would be to simply find all cases where `%...%` exist, run `strip_tags()` on the content and then see if it is a field match.  Using `preg_replace_callback()` might be suitable for this:

```
$pattern = '/\%(?![0-9])([a-zA-z0-9_-]+)\%/U'; // note use of ungreedy match

$cleaned_string = preg_replace_callback($pattern, function($matches) {
   $field_name = strip_tags($matches[1]);
   // I assume you have custom fields and values in an associative array with field name as key.
   // You can change this part to match your actual case
   if(array_key_exists($field_name, $array_of_custom_fields)) {
       return $array_of_custom_fields[$field_name];
   } else {
       return ''; // empty string since field doesn't match
   }
}, $message);
```